# Symbolic axis values - strange sequence

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to get symbolic values x1, x2, x3, x4 on x axis and C(x1),...,C(x4) on y axis.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        symbolic x coords={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$},
        symbolic y coords={$C(x_1)$, $C(x_2)$, $C(x_3)$,                
        $C(x_4)$}]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the result is:

[image]

How can I get the right plot?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to enter as many entries as the ticks. Here you have 5 ticks but 3 labels.

Comment: Hello @percusse, why have I 3 labels? It seems that there are x and y labels.

Comment: Count the tick marks on your axes. There are 5 each. But your labels are 3 and 4. So pgfplots is reusing some of them.

Comment: Sorry @percusse, where are 3 and 4? I see only the 5 ticks. Can you explain me please? I'm a beginner of Latex.

Comment: How many arguments did you supply to `symbolic x coords`?

Comment: I have 4 arguments for symbolic x coords, and 4 for symbolic y coords. I tried also with 5 arguments: symbolic x coords={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$}, symbolic y coords={$C(x_1)$, $C(x_2)$, $C(x_3)$, $C(x_4)$, $C(x_5)$}], but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        %symbolic x coords={$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$, $x_4$},
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in

> Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 12.

and

[image]

`symbolic x coords={$x_1$, $x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$}` means that `$x_1$` is used as the normalized value `0` and `$x_2$` is used as the normalized value `1`. So adding this option will replace the tick values 0.2 and 0.4 by `$x_1$` and 0.6, 0.8 and 1 by `$x_2$`:

[image]

---

If the desired result is

[image]

you could set the minimum and maximum for `x` and `y`, the maximum for the ticks and the tick distances and add `0` to the symbolic coords:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        symbolic x coords={0,$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$},
        xmin={[normalized]0},
        xmax={[normalized]5},
        xtickmax={[normalized]4},
        xtick distance=1,
        symbolic y coords={0,$C(x_1)$,$C(x_2)$,$C(x_3)$,$C(x_4)$},
        ymin={[normalized]0},
        ymax={[normalized]5},
        ytickmax={[normalized]4},
        ytick distance=1
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But here is also a suggestion without symbolic coords:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
        xmin=0,xmax=5,
        xtick={1,...,4},
        xticklabel={$x_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}}$},
        ymin=0,ymax=5,
        ytick={1,...,4},
        yticklabel={$C(x_{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\tick}})$},
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @esdd, thank you for your solution. It is very clear.